# AngularJS nested controller with parameter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-controller

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.7:

I have a controller 'mainCtrl' which gets an array of object from a factory. In my HTML i want to call a child controller trough an expression in ng-repeat,
if possible with parameters. I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="module in modules">
    <div ng-include="'modules/' + module.type + '.html'" ng-controller="{{ module.type + 'Ctrl(' + module.data + ')' }}">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Create a custom directive for this

Comment: is it possible to call the directive with an expression? something like this: `<{{ variable }}></{{ variable }}`